# awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767

Tags: awk, sh

when i am running my shell script in ubuntu 14.04 i am getting an error like below

```
awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767
    FILENAME="ensemble_features/Training_BOOKS_POS_Bigram_with_stemming_BOOLEAN_FVT.csv" FNR=1 NR=1
cut: invalid byte, character or field list
Try 'cut --help' for more information.
-1
cut: invalid byte, character or field list
Try 'cut --help' for more information.
6656
user@user-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z410:~/Thesis/BOOKS$ bash Training_POS_Uni_Bi.sh
awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767
    FILENAME="ensemble_features/Training_BOOKS_POS_Bigram_with_stemming_BOOLEAN_FVT.csv" FNR=1 NR=1
cut: invalid byte, character or field list
Try 'cut --help' for more information.
-1
cut: invalid byte, character or field list
Try 'cut --help' for more information.
6656
```

i am adding my script below

```
cd /home/user/Thesis/BOOKS/Features/Training/POSITIVE/
fname="ensemble_features"
mkdir $fname

cp /home/user/Thesis/BOOKS/Features/Training/POSITIVE/Training_BOOKS_POS_unigram_FVT_with_stemming_BOOLEAN.csv ensemble_features/
cp /home/user/Thesis/BOOKS/Features/Training/POSITIVE/Training_BOOKS_POS_Bigram_with_stemming_BOOLEAN_FVT.csv ensemble_features/


mkdir "proces"
cnt=0
for file in $fname/*
do
    #Number of columns
    num=`awk 'BEGIN {FS=",";c=0};{if (c==0 ){print NF; c=1}}END{}' $file`
    if [[ cnt -eq 0 ]];then
        cut -d, -f $num $file >class.csv
        cnt=1;
    fi
    num=$((num-1))
    echo $num
    nfname=`basename $file`

    #Cut the columns
    cut -d',' -f1-$num $file > proces/cutlast$nfname
done
#Paste multiple csv
paste -d',' proces/* > comb.csv
paste -d, comb.csv class.csv > Training_BOOKS_Unigram_Bigram_POS_Ensemble_Features_BOOLEAN.csv
rm comb.csv
rm class.csv
rm -r proces
rm -r ensemble_features
```

my input files contain 38453 columns and 6656 columns respectively.Anybody can help me to correct this error?

Comment: Don't use `awk`? You may have better luck with e.g. Python (`import csv`).

Comment: how can i edit my pgm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On ubuntu awk is a soft link to some variant of awk, nowadays by default it is mawk. Try to install gawk. gawk does not have a limitation on the number of fields in a record.

BTW, python may be a better long term solution, if you got the time to learn it.

Comment: +1  https://groups.google.com/a/broadinstitute.org/forum/#!topic/xhmm-users/_Ocdzq06r1E also suggests use gawk, which does not have fields limit.

Comment: Correct, `gawk` comes without a maximum number of columns. Besides that, Python is ages slower than `awk` and that's why not an alternative for bigger files.