# terminal error of AWK indicates limit exceeded

Tags: linux, awk, terminal

I have a big data, contains values. I know the number of rows, but the number of columns in each row can be varied.

I am trying to copy specific columns of it (if exist) to another file.
so I used the terminal of Linux with this code:

```
awk {'print $2'} file.csv
```

And I got this error:

```
 program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767
FILENAME="20181024_d1_0830_0900.csv" FNR=18 NR=18
```

Any solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292787/awk-program-limit-exceeded-maximum-number-of-fields-size-32767)

Comment: `awk '{print $2}' file.csv > newfile`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `awk` hits a line which has more then 32767 fields.

If you know the position of the information that you are trying to find, you can substring line with `cut` then use awk.

or you can use/install `gawk`